# connect function Error 10047 (winsock2)

Tags: c++, winapi, winsock2

So I copied some test code from the MSDN site that uses basic windows socket functions. Here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcipip.h>
#include <wchar.h>


int main()
{

    int iResult = 0;

    //----------------------
    // Initialize Winsock
    WSADATA wsaData;
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        wprintf(L"WSAStartup function failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }
    //----------------------
    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    SOCKET ConnectSocket;
    ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        wprintf(L"socket function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    //----------------------
    // The sockaddr_in structure specifies the address family,
    // IP address, and port of the server to be connected to.

    int I = sizeof(sockaddr_in);
        sockaddr_in clientService;
    clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;     
        clientService.sin_port = htons(5000);
    in_addr *s = (in_addr*)malloc(sizeof(in_addr));
    s->s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    clientService.sin_addr = (in_addr_t)s;

    iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, (sockaddr*)&clientService,I);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"connect function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        iResult = closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
            wprintf(L"closesocket function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    wprintf(L"Connected to server.\n");

    iResult = closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"closesocket function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles just fine. But when I run the program the command prompt screen displays the following error message:

> connection failed with error: 10047

Now I know that Error 10047 indicates an error in the address structure. I tried using `inet_pto`n but that leads to a segment error (memory access violation) as `inet_pton` uses the `memcpy` function. So what is going on here? Is the `connect` function improperly implemented? Maybe there is another way to specify the address structure.

Comment: `Is the connect function improperly implemented?` -- [No](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html).

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
sockaddr_in clientService;
clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
clientService.sin_port = htons(27015);
```

Seems like your setting .sin_addr.s_addr in an ambiguous way.

If it turns out the above, isn't the problem, then perhaps you have IP6 protocols truned on but no IP4 which would be why AF_NET is failing and required AF_NET6.

Comment: So how do I turn on IP4 protocols and disable IP6 protocols?

Comment: @Mr X - Specifically, that depends on what operating system you're using. But generally the settings are in your network settings / properties.

Comment: LastCoder, I'm using windows7.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the problem is this line here:

```
clientService.sin_addr = (in_addr_t)s;
```

You're assigning an in_addr pointer to an in_addr object. Dereference the pointer like so (also note that if you remove the cast the compiler will catch the problem:

```
clientService.sin_addr = *s;
```

LastCoder's approach would be easier, though. There's no reason to `malloc()` a separate in_addr structure just to copy it.